# How to check scene object's type in Godot 4

Tags: game-development, godot, godot4

I have a scene called Planet and a script like that:

```
1. extends Node2D
2. 
3. @export var radius: float
4. 
5. func collide(other:Node2D):
6.      if other is Planet :
7.          if(radius > other.radius):
8.              print("I win")
9.          else:
10.             print("I loose")
11.     else:
12.         print("Not a planet")
```

The line 6 gives me an error `Could not find type "Planet" in the current scope.`
How do I do these kinds of tests where I check that a scene object is of particular type(current scene's type)?
Also, is it possible to specify a parameter type (line 5) to a particular scene? Smth like

```
func collide(other:Planet):
```

I know, it doesn't change much since the language is dynamically typed. But that would help with documentation and maybe autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDScript type "hints" are hints. They are actually type declarations, and they are enforced in runtime. GDScript is a *progressively typed langauge*, meaning that you can start programming fully dynamically and then steadily add static typing, up to a point, so it is not fully dynamic and not fully static.

---

There are two ways the syntax `other:Planet` will work:

- You can add a `class_name` to the plane script, at the top:

  ```
  class_name Planet

  # Planet Code
  ```

  Then in other scripts you can use `obj:Planet`.
- You declare a constant set to preloading the script, also at the top, but on the script that uses it:

  ```
  const Planet = preload("res://path/to/planet/script.gd")

  # Code that uses Planet and has stuff like obj:Planet in it
  ```

---

As per checking the type in runtime...

First, if you have a variable and you have no idea what kind of thing it has, you can use `typeof`. And that will return a constant from the enum `Variant.Type`, in this case I expect it to be `TYPE_OBJECT`.

And second you can check the class of an object if the `is` operator, like this `obj is Planet`.

---

However, if you do not know the class and you want to find it out. Then try to get the script of the object with `obj.get_script()`.

If it has a `Script`, up until Godot 4.2.x you need to iterate over [`ProjectSettings.get_global_class_list`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_projectsettings.html#class-projectsettings-method-get-global-class-list) to find the name of the class, if it has any. From Godot 4.3 onwards you will be able to use `script.get_global_name()`.

On the other hand, if the `Object` has no `Script`, then its class is `obj.get_class()`.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. BTW, I didn't know GDScript in fact enforces type checks. I thought it would work like Python, not honoring the type hints at runtime.